# ASCII characters that become check boxes in Confluence markup

Tags: checkbox, markup, confluence

Are there ASCII characters that can be imported into or pasted onto a Confluence page to create check boxes (for tasks)?

These can be done manually by typing in a Confluence page or using Insert > Markup
User mention (at symbol and user name)… done manually by typing @ and a name.
Checkbox.. done manually by typing [] and then a short description of the task.

Pasting this into a Markup window creates a table with the text that is between the | (pipe) symbols:
||Heading 1||Heading 2||
|Cell 1|Cell 2|

Pasting this into a Markup window creates a user mention:
[~id]
For example, for John Doe it may be:
[~jdoe]

However, I do not know what to paste to create the checkboxes or user mentions.

My goal is to assemble data into tables with a python script. I will request that people approve or reject by checking the appropriate boxes. With my current knowledge, I can have the text that will go next to the check boxes and I’ll need to go through and manually edit to force Confluence to create the checkboxes. But since there was a solution to the other components, I thought I’d ask.